# How do I return a Laravel Http response as a json object instead of an array?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the the Laravel Http Client to get a collection of users from the Microsoft Graph API. My code as follows is:

```
public function index()
    {
        $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                        ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users');
        foreach($response['value'] as $user)
        {
            echo $user['displayName'] . '<br/>';
        }
    }
```

However, I want to be able to access user details as properties such as:

```
public function index()
    {
        $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                        ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users');
        foreach($response->value as $user)
        {
            echo $user->displayName . '<br/>';
        }
    }
```

How would I go about this?

**UPDATE**

```
public function index()
    {
        $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                        ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users')
                        ->throw();
        $users = $response->object();
        foreach($users->value as $user)
        {
            echo $user->displayName . '<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: return response as `$response->object()`  .
Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below Code it's working properly.**

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                    ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users');            
    $response = $response->object();
    foreach($response->value as $user)
    {
        echo $user->displayName . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                    ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users');
    $response = json_decode(json_encode($response->json()));
    foreach($response->value as $user)
    {
        echo $user->displayName . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::withToken($this->accessToken)
                    ->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users');
    $response = (object) $response->json();
    foreach($response->value as $user)
    {
        echo $user->displayName . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\Client\Response::$value

Comment: I have to edit the answer please try this code. In my case, this code works properly.

Comment: what is going on with this: `json_decode(json_encode($response->json()))`?  You call `json()` to make a json string, right? Then you call `json_encode()` on that already json-encoded string, then you call `json_decode()` on that double-json-encoded string?

Comment: In Laravel, response->json() often returns an array, so I converted it to a string with the json_encode function and then converted the same JSON string to an object with the json_decode function.